# Objective-C append image thumbnails onto the end of a view

Tags: objective-c, addsubview, uistackview

I'm trying to append images onto a view and have them display a thumbnail in a nice neat row. The issue I'm having is that it appears all images simply get added on top on each other in the corner as only the last image in the array is dispayed.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


 self.notesField.delegate = self;
 NSString *userName = ((ontracAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).userName;

 self.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date Created: %@ \nCreated By: %@",[NSDate date], userName];

 if (self.noteText != nil) {
    self.notesField.text = self.noteText;
    self.notesField.editable = NO;
    self.textLabel.hidden = TRUE;

 }
 [self.view resignFirstResponder];
 if ([self.imageArray count] != 0) {
    for (UIImage *image in imageArray) {
        NSLog(@"Image %@", image);
        [self addImageToScreen:image];
    }
 }
 NSLog(@"imageArray %@", imageArray);
 NSLog(@"self.textField.text  %@", self.textField.text );
 NSLog(@"self.notesField.text %@", self.notesField.text);
}

-(void) addImageToScreen:(UIImage*) image;
{
 int adjustHeight = 0;
 int adjustWidth = 10;
 int imagesInARow = 7;

 int imageHeight = 75;
 int imageWidth = 75;

 int count = [self.imageArray count];
 self.numberOfPhotosLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count];

 if (count > 1 && count < imagesInARow) {
    adjustHeight = 0;
    adjustWidth = (20 * [self.imageArray indexOfObject:image]) + ([self.imageArray indexOfObject:image] * imageWidth);
 }


 UIButton* container = [[UIButton alloc] init ];


 CGRect frame = CGRectMake(adjustWidth, 5, imageWidth, imageHeight);
 [container setTag:[self.imageArray indexOfObject:image]];
 [container setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [container setFrame:frame];
 [container addTarget:self action:@selector(displayFullScreenImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];


 UIStackView *photosView = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
 container.frame = photosView.bounds;

 [photosView addSubview:container];


 [self.view addSubview:photosView];

}
```

Comment: Where do you add the image to the `imageArray`? From the code I would assume this array is always empty.

Comment: That is added elsewhere but i've checked the array and it's not empty.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to make sure. Then, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `addArrangedSubview` of `UIStackView` instead of `addSubview`.

And you should add all the Buttons to the same `UIStackView`. So, add a property for the `UIStackView` to your class, initialize it in `viewDidLoad` (or in the storyboard) and add the buttons to that stack view in `addImageToScreen`.

Comment: Ok so i now have `[photosView addArrangedSubview:container];` and it's producing the same results.

Comment: OK so i've given it a go but having no luck. What i've done is added `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStackView *photosView;` in the .h file.

Added `self.photosView = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 500, 75)];` in the viewDidLoad and edited the following line in addImageToScreen `[self.photosView addSubview:container];
    
    
    [self.view addSubview:self.photosView];` The results are the same :/

Comment: I should say that i'm an objective-c newbie too